# KDE missing menu (red cross)

Tags: kde

As I've said [on Tuesday](https://superuser.com/questions/320808/x11-libraries-corrupted-by-virtualbox-crash), the last VirtualBox crash corrupted anything related to X11.

After two days and reinstalling nearly all libraries I could got the KDM/GDM working, but the is still one thing missing: the KDE menu button.

[image]

I don't know which "launcher" has failed and the logs aren't helping either. The other icons with "?" are ok because they are used only in clients who log in using NIS (a mount their homes via NFS).

Comment: Solved! An "apt-get install --reinstall plasma-desktop" did the trick.

Comment: You should post this as an answer, and accept it. People will know that this issue has been resolved.